# There are more than one commits in Jenkins projects

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket

In my Jenkins Pipeline project I have 3 branches. Main, B1 and B2.
When I do make a change in B1, auto build kicks in ==> with '1 commits' message in the 'Stage View'.
Then I did the manual build on same branch then it shows 'No Changes' message in the 'Stage View'.

Again, I made some changes, pushed code to Bitbucket it shows '11 Commits' message in the 'Stage View' auto build.

Now I switched to Main branch, did some changes, pushed code to Bitbucket it shows '10 Commits' message in the 'Stage View'.

Now I switched to B1 branch, manual build without pushing code it shows '21 Commits' message in the 'Stage View'.

The sequence of switch to branches to branches and git push I did as above.
Can anyone tell me why this big number in Commit # in stage view?

I have tested/tried without even pushing any code bitbucket.

Comment: IMO the commits Jenkins is reporting are counted from the previous Jenkins build. The count isn't done against "base branch" or something to that tune. If you want to understand the difference between base branch and this branch _as of the build time_, you need to do it yourself by running `git` commands.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do to understand the commit count better, try if your Jenkins Pipeline configuration is set to track "*Git SCM HEAD*" or "*Local changes*".

Before a manual build, try running **git status** in your terminal on the Jenkins workspace, this shows any un-pushed changes that might be contributing to the high commit count and consider using a feature branch workflow, this involves creating a separate branch for each change, pushing it to Bitbucket, and then merging it into the main branch to help keep track of changes more clearly.

By understanding how Jenkins tracks changes and potentially adjusting your workflow, you can get a better picture of what's reflected in the "*Stage View*" commit count.

The high number of commits you're observing in the Jenkins Pipeline "*Stage View*" is likely a result of how Jenkins keeps track of changes during builds.

- For example in build with "**1 Commit**”, on `B1`

This scenario seems accurate. When you make a change and push it to B1, the automatic build recognizes that one commit for processing.

- With the manual build with "**No Changes**" on `B1`

This situation may occur because Jenkins considers the build as the reference point for comparison. Since there have been no alterations to the code on `B1` since the build (which processed the single commit) it displays "**No Changes**".

- With the automatic build with "**11 Commits**" on `B1` (*following changes*)

There could be two reasons I think, you made multiple changes and pushed them simultaneously, so provably Jenkins detects these commits compared to the automatic build reference, and If you didn't push all changes together there might be leftover commits from, before the build, because these are included in the build resulting in a count.

- With "**10 Changes**” on Main Branch, like `B1` this probably shows the number of recent updates made since the last build on the Main branch.
- And with "**21 Changes**" on Manual Build (`B1`) without Push, Its possible that Jenkins is set up to monitor modifications made locally in your workspace not just the commits that have been pushed.

If you've made adjustments, on `B1` after the build (*without pushing them*) Jenkins might be tallying all those un pushed changes.